# "for" loop and perfect numbers

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, perfect-numbers

Have to create program that list all perfect number( sum of factors = number ) 1 - 1000.

- this is for a java class, need to only use "for" loops

I have checked my code 100 times and getting no output, I am missing a logical error somewhere, could someone help me out?

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  // variables
  int total = 0;
  final int LIMIT = 1000;

  // for loop to test all numbers 1-1000
  for(int i = 1; i <= LIMIT; i++)
  {
    // if statement
    if((i != 1) && (total == i - 1))
    {
      // prints perfect number
      System.out.println((i - 1) + " is a perfect number");
      // resets total value
      total = 0;
    }
    // gets and add factors as total
    for(int divider = 1; divider < i; divider++)
    {
      if((i % divider) == 0)
      {
        total += divider;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: Yes, please do.  We can't write your answer for you.  But we can help you get un-stuck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your big problem is that you only reset `total` if you find a perfect number. If you don't find a perfect number, you continue adding divisors for the next number to the old total. You need to start fresh for every `i`.

Rearranging your program in the following way should help:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int LIMIT = 1000;
    for (int i = 0; i <= LIMIT; i++) {
        // Declare total here, inside the loop, so values from previous
        // iterations are discarded.
        int total = 0;
        for (/* your code here */) {
            // add up divisors
            // your code here
        }
        // compare to i, rather than always computing the total for the
        // previous number and comparing to that.
        if (/* your code here */) {
            // print output
            // your code here
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should move `total = 0;` outside of your if statement.  Your total is adding up and never being reset.

Comment: It's not just that, look at where he's adding up `total` and where he's checking it.

Comment: He's checking it in the following iteration.  I don't know why he's doing that, but it should still function as expected, possibly with the exception of the loop ending one iteration prematurely.

Comment: Ah, yeah I see what you mean. Though I'd imagine checking the given iteration would make it more understandable.

Comment: I couldn't agree more :)  I was being a bit lazy and then @user2357112 decided to post a nice answer.  I would imagine he could have pasted the OP's code into those comments though :\

Comment: Sure. I'm assuming he didn't so that the OP would fill in the blank rather than just copy-pasting what he put down.

Answer (score 0):

I reccomend to split your algorithm to different parts, so you can focus on smaller tasks at time.

1. Find factors of number `i`. A method that gets a number and return an arrays of it's factors.
2. Sum factors together. A simple method that takes an array and returns it's the sum.
3. Main loop: just check if sum(factors(i)) == i

You can start with the more easy ones (Hint: 2 and 3) and then maybe search for some not-totally-inefficient ways to implement 1

Comment: There's a good chance he's just learning to program and is just now beginning to learn about loops and hasn't gotten to creating methods yet :)

Answer (score 0):

(total == i - 1) will never match when you start with total=0 and i>1.

Answer (score 0):

You were close.  Just need to re-evaluate your logic a bit.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // variables
        int total = 0;
        final int LIMIT = 1000;

        // for loop to test all numbers 1-1000
        for (int i = 1; i <= LIMIT; i++) {

            // gets and add factors first
            for (int divider = 1; divider < i; divider++) {
                if ((i % divider) == 0) {
                    total += divider;
                }

            }

            // then check if sum == number
            // also just print i instead of - 1
            if ((i != 1) && (total == i)) {
                // prints perfect number
                System.out.println((i) + " is a perfect number");

            }

            // alway reset when we are done with a number
            total = 0;

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 for(int i=1;i<1000;i++)
    {
        int k=0;

        for(int j=1;j<i;j++)
        {
            if(i % j==0)
            {   
                k+=j;
            }

        }
        if(k==i)
        {
            System.out.println(k);
        }
    }
```